# How to insert Html data in lotus notes document (email,task,etc.) body using C++ api?

Tags: c++, lotus-notes

I am using Lotus notes 8.5 c++ api to create a new notes document like email,calendars, tasks,etc. i am not able to put html data in any notes document body.When i insert html data, it shows as Html code. however i can put plain text easily using following api.

```
LnDocument Mydocument;
Lnstring strval= "xyz";
Lntext Txt;
Txt.Setvalue(strval);
Mydocument.Createitem("Body", Txt, LNITEMFLAGS_SUMMARY, LNITEMOPTION_DELETE_APPEND);
```

How can i Put html Data in Body field?

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/How_to_create_and_send_an_email_message_containing_an_HTML_body_using_an_agent) has some good instructions on how to create a HTML email

It is aimed at Lotusscript but shouldn't be too hard to convert to the C++ api.  The gist is that you'll have to create a NotesMimeEntity and set its text to the HTML you've generated.

Comment: Their is no datatype as NotesMimeEntity or NoteMimeHeader in LotusNotes C++ Library. How can i Create NotesMimeEntity ?. Should i have to include any class or library  to use MimeEntity?. Or should I have to Create it using LotusScript.? can u give some code of lotusScript if i have to create it using LotusScript?

Comment: The link in my answer (click on "tutorial") shows an example written in LotusScript.  It seems the C/C++ API doesn't offer the same convenience around working with MIME that is found in LotusScript and Java.  There's not much help out there on the topic, but perhaps [Bob Balaban's post](http://bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/geek-o-terica-16-easy-conversion-of-notes-documents-to-mime-format-part-2?opendocument&comments#anc1) on MIME is useful.  It uses C# to call wrappers around the C API to build up a MIME document.

Comment: Wasn't the C++ API deprecated back in the early R5 codestream (killed on or about R5.0.2c along with the OLE API)? AFAIK, what is there now is just a backwards-compatibility vestige and new dev isn't supported. The COM API is the One True Way unless you drop to C (apart from native and Java).